# Кодировка имен файлов в Zip

Tags: c#, zip, ziparchive

Есть zip-архив, который нужно распаковать с помощью SharpCompress (требование начальника использовать именно эту библиотеку), но при распаковке архива русские буквы превращаются в кракозябры (например название папки "исходные данные" превращаются в "¿ßσ«ñ¡δÑ ñá¡¡δÑ").

```
using Stream stream = File.OpenRead(archive);
using var reader = ReaderFactory.Open(stream);
    while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
    {
      if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
      {
        reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(dectDir, extractionOptions);
      }
    }
```

Я пробовал сделать распаковку с использованием 1251 кодировки, но это также не помогает, "исходные данные" превращаются в "Ёбе®¤­лҐ ¤ ­­лҐ".

```
var opts = new ReaderOptions();
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
opts.ArchiveEncoding = new()
{
    CustomDecoder = (data, x, y) =>
    {
        return encoding.GetString(data);
    }
};
using Stream stream = File.OpenRead(archive);
using var reader = ReaderFactory.Open(stream,opts);
while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
{
    if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
    {
        reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(dectDir, extractionOptions);
    }
}
```

PS. В перспективе архивы могут быть не только zip, поэтому используется stream, что позволяет автоматически распознавать тип архива.

Comment: Использовать SharpCompress это просьба сеньера/тимлида который вас менторит или  абстрактного **начальника** который даже вашего имени не знает?

Comment: А по факту какая кодировка-то у вас в zip?

Comment: Это cp866 прочитанный как cp437

Comment: Но вообще в zip кодировка не стандартизирована и, например, во всторенном виндовом архиваторе зависит от языка системы ‍♂️